# What is wrong with MySql LIKE operator on utf8_turkish_ci collation?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've a table like below:

> ```
> wordId     |   word      
> ---------------------------------
> 1          |   axxe
> 2          |   test word
> 3          |   another test word
> ```

I'm trying to run the query below to find the records beginning with the letters "ax".

```
SELECT * FROM `words` WHERE word LIKE 'ax%'
```

MySQL cannot find anything.

*But*, if I try one of the queries below I can see the correct record (the word "axxe") on the results.

```
SELECT * FROM `words` WHERE word='axxe'

SELECT * FROM `words` WHERE word LIKE '%ax%'

SELECT * FROM `words` WHERE word LIKE 'a%'
```

Why can't MySQL find the correct value for the first query? I've tried to run this both on the command line and phpMyAdmin but the result is the same.

This is SHOW CREATE TABLE output:

```
CREATE TABLE `words` (
 `wordId` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
 `word` text collate utf8_turkish_ci NOT NULL
 PRIMARY KEY  (`word`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2853 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_turkish_ci
```

Comment: Works for me: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/53090/1

Comment: Maybe your table is case sensitive?

Comment: What are you asking? This seems to work as expected.

Comment: I would surmise your 'words.word' column has preceding values (non display characters such as tab or space or enter.  so does `SELECT * FROM words WHERE trim(word) LIKE 'ax%'` give you wordid 1? if so you have leading spaces if not you have a non display character in word preceding the a in ax.  since %ax% works it's a reasonable assumption.

Comment: Is it possible you have a space in front of the axxe entry?

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat how can I learn this? + words that I try completely consist of lowercase chars.

Comment: Could you copy-paste the four words from the actual table? If `axxe` happens to be `аххе` (looks the same, but it is in Cyrillic) MySql wouldn't be able to find it.

Comment: @D.L No, I am sure it doesn't.

Comment: @xQbert I've thought this first. But also "WHERE word='axxe'" works too and added the values by hand.

Comment: how are you talking to MySQL, is it CLI or PHP or WorkBench, etc?

Comment: @Martin PhpMyAdmin and CLI. trying on both of them.

Comment: ok wierd...  `='axxe'` works but `like 'ax%'` doesn't.... and like `%ax%'` works... yeh.... I just don't see how that possible on the same table in the same database without changes in between.

Comment: @xQbert wierdest thing I've seen. I tried to think it is due to server configuration or something.

Comment: Ok try this: `SELECT * FROM words WHERE word LIKE CONCAT('ax','%')`

Comment: @Martin no it doesn't either.

Comment: same session/window?  one window using a different connection and uncommitted and the other uncommitted but on the same connection so transaction still open; thus one works other doesn't?  I'm graspin because it should work; so this is just the odd stuff I start thinking about.

Comment: @xQbert. No. I encountered with this error while working on my project. After hundreds of failed try, I've started to try it on phpMyAdmin and CLI to understand what is the problem.

Comment: @xQbert The table has 4-5 thousands rows. Is that number huge for a MySql? Could this be the problem?

Comment: no, that is a trivial sized table for MySQL

Comment: @Martin then where should I look at? Could wrong configuration or something cause this kind of problem? I've no idea anymore.

Comment: can you edit your question and show the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, cheers

Comment: Well we know it works elsewhere so it must be a config/environment settings now the question is what the hell could it it be...

Comment: I would redirect the select output to a file and take a look at it using "od -a file".  Something not quite right with the actual contents.

Comment: if it was a data issue (extra characters/white space etc) `='axxe'` wouldn't return a record; but it does.

Comment: Did you check if the word "axxe" does not have an extra withe space? Like " axxe"?

Comment: @xQbert - Unless his client is somehow encoding the 'axxe'...

Comment: said he tried on command line I don't see how that would happen; but shrug

Comment: @Martin I've added the output of SHOW CREATE TABLE.

Comment: Maybe... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32583922/mysql-table-collation-utf8-turkish-ci-to-utf8-general-ci problem with Collation ?  No... same collation on table and data entry...

Comment: @D.L I've thought it too. I've deleted everything on the table and re-entered by hand. The result is the same. I am sure this is not a data error.

Comment: I think @xQbert might be on the right track with the encoding.

Comment: Is X a different letter in Turkish? (honest question)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turkish_alphabet Wikipedia doesn't even list X as a letter in Turkish...

Comment: maybe `where word like ('ax%' COLLATE utf8_turkish_ci)`? based on :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25428529/effects-of-updating-a-table-with-rows-from-utf8-turkish-ci-to-utf8-general-ci  since table column word is defined in utf8_turkish_ci  @RocketHazmat can you update your fiddle to turkish collation and try see if we can reproduce?

Comment: @Jacob H As a turkish speaking person, I know. But the table also contains turkish chars.

Comment: Yes, but how does SQL know how to compare 'AX' when X does not exist in the collation? Try what @xQbert is suggesting with COLLATE

Comment: @JacobH You're right. But I tried. It doesn't work either. Also the result is same with the turkish chars too.

Comment: Maybe try `ascii(substring(word, 2, 1))` to confirm what character 'x' really is?

Comment: What coolation was the database created using?https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-applications.html  I'm not an expert in this area so I'll back out for now but this is where I would spend my time; since we know it works in mysql with default settings and the use of utf8_turkish_ci is not the default.

Comment: @xQbert I am trying it now. thank you

Comment: Known bug perhaps: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=24921  nope that's falcon engine :(

Comment: Also, you might check the database version and see if you see the same behavior in a newer version,

Comment: Seems others have similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22454999/mysql-query-select-like-with-diacritic-turkish-letters or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11216079/turkish-character-encoding-with-mysql?

Comment: This many comments and only one upvote on the question (sigh)  its a great question and people we are all stuggling with it!

Comment: @xQbert yes, I guess most of people don't believe this could happen :) by the way, thanks for links. I'm working on it.

Comment: I didn't think it could at first then when I realized = 'axxe' did work; I know it was a config/environment thing just needed to figure out what it could be and collation seemed to make the most sense.  Other stack posts and articles lead me to believe it was likely the culprit; I just don't know how to fix it.  Maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10444004/mysql-turkish-character

Comment: Any chance you could use regular expressions as a workaround?  Just a thought if you need a quick solution...And assuming you don't see similar behavior there. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html. SELECT * FROM words WHERE word REGEXP '^ax.*'

Comment: Maybe this is crazy but... cast both as binary?

Comment: Just some more good reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582519/php-mysql-turkish-character-encoding-and-comparison

Comment: The issue appears to be the MySQL understanding of the character collation, `utf8_turkish_ci`. A solution could be to change the table and column collation type to `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`. Let me know if this works. MySQL [has a well documented](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29929677/3536236) issue with standard `utf8_` collations *not* being full UTF-8 complient.

Comment: Or possibly try `utf8mb4_turkish_ci`, if the unicode general collation doesn't have all the characters (apparently it may not)

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR:

> Update your MySQL version.

---

I created a simulation of your problem here:

Create table:

```
CREATE TABLE `turky` (
 `id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `word` text COLLATE utf8_turkish_ci NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_turkish_ci
```

Insert data:

```
INSERT INTO `turky` (`id`, `word`) VALUES
(1, 'axxe'),
(2, 'test word'),
(3, 'axxxxxe'),
(4, 'another test word');
```

---

Run test query (that works):

```
SELECT * FROM `turky` WHERE `word`='axxe'
```

Result:

> 1, 'axxe',

Run test query 2 (that works):

```
SELECT * FROM `turky` WHERE word LIKE '%ax%'
```

Result:

> 1, 'axxe',
> 3, 'axxxxxe',

Run test query 3 (that works):

```
SELECT * FROM `turky` WHERE word LIKE 'a%'
```

Result:

> 1, 'axxe',
> 3, 'axxxxxe',
> 4, 'another test word';

---

Run test query 4 (that does not work originally):

```
SELECT * FROM `turky` WHERE `word` LIKE 'ax%'
```

Result:

> 1, 'axxe',
> 3, 'axxxxxe',

This works in MySQL, using PHPMyAdmin.

**Versions**:
MySQL: 5.6.35
PHPMyAdmin: 4.6.6

---

The current Turkish alphabet doesn't contain the letter "x" so this fact may [*probably not*] be causing some obscure interference with the SQL sorting process (as in a lack of language guidance when looking for this character).

Web searching Turkish language bugs in MySQL and while there are half a dozen none of them appear to be for your specific instance.

But the only option here that I can see from my own testing (above), using the table and SQL details you've given us, is that you have an older version of MySQL that includes some turkish language bugs.

---

## If your MySQL version is up to date

*(or at least, more recent than mine)*

Then the issue seems to be specific to your setup and your data, so I highly doubt we can find and reproduce this issue `:-(`

---

**More Diagnostic stuff**:
As commented by [Jacob H](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43877437/what-is-wrong-with-mysql-like-operator-on-utf8-turkish-ci-collation/43880607#comment74791544_43877437), see if this issue still occurs after *casting to binary*:

```
SELECT * FROM `turky` WHERE BINARY `word` LIKE CONCAT(BINARY 'ax','%');
```

Result:

> 1, 'axxe',
> 3, 'axxxxxe',